# Elastic Search - Efficient/Compact "Not In" Operator

Tags: elasticsearch

So I wanted the equivalent of doing an sql `not in` query such as this:

```
select * from test where id not in (1,2,3);
```

Initially I was thinking more in SQL, and it took me an hour to understand the philosophy behind elastic search, the query builder, and the underlying rest API.

```
I have come up with the following which however seems very inefficient:

public <T> MyQueryBuilder notIn(String field, List<String> values) {
        if (values != null & values.size() > 0) {

            Iterator<String> it = values.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                MatchQueryBuilder match =  new MatchQueryBuilder(field, it.next());
                match.operator(Operator.OR);
                boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(match);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

And this generates the following `rest call body`:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must_not" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "myId" : {
          "query" : "b5359d78-5e0e-4b09-af2c-d4c921ea6a15",
          "operator" : "OR"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "match" : {
        "myId" : {
          "query" : "e679ce6d-a7a1-48a0-b06e-54752fbd7e31",
          "operator" : "OR"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

So is there a better more efficient way?
**Update:** Efficient might have been the wrong word. A more concise/compact expression....

Thanks!

### Update

I also tried the following but it does not work like an sql `not in` expression:

```
{    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
                      "bool": {
                            "filter": [
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "myId": [
                                     "c1928da6-80d0-475a-9025-b3ebd934a576" ,
                                    "d2",
                                    "d3",
                                    "d4"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
            },
            "must_not" : {
                "match" : {
                    "myId" :
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 2

I think the following actually works, and works better:

```
{    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
                      "bool": {
                            "filter": [
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "myId": [
                                     "c1928da6-80d0-475a-9025-b3ebd934a576" ,
                                    "d2",
                                    "d3",
                                    "d4"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work even though the notation seems to be more concise .

```
public <T> CoolQueryBuilder notInV2(String field, List<String> values) {
    if (values != null & values.size() > 0) {
        //boolQuery() = constructor for boolean query
        boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(boolQuery().filter(termsQuery(field, values)));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's inefficient? Do you experience slower than expected results? You may want to separate the data to a different index

Comment: @raam86 Updated my answer. I would like something more concise/compact. Also, I have a habit of thinking of large statements as inefficient.